# Counter not decrementing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable which serves as a counter in my javascript file. So if the user adds another form entry, the counter increments and if the user removes an entry, the counter decrements.

The counter serves as a limit to how many entries the user can add which for me the max is 5.

Now my problem is the remove action doesnt seem to make an effect in my counter and it doesnt decrement it.

Here is my code:

```
    var count = 1;
    $('.multiple-fields .btn-add').click(function(e) {
        if (count <=4 ){
            e.preventDefault();

            var multiple_fields = $(this).parents('.multiple-fields');
            var current_entry = $(this).parents('.entry:first');
            var new_entry = $(current_entry.clone()).appendTo(multiple_fields);

            new_entry.find('input').val('');
            new_entry.find('select').val('');
            new_entry.find('.btn-add').removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove').html('<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>');
            new_entry.find('.btn-remove').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parents('.entry').remove();

                return false;
            });
            new_entry.find('.select-course, .select-dormitory').change(function() {
                $.campusHandler.update($(this));
            });
            count++;
            console.log(count);
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log(count);
            $.messageHandler.showMessageBox('error_line_max');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $('.multiple-fields .btn-remove').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('.entry').remove();
        count--;
        console.log(count);

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: You have `'count'` in quotes in your code, right after `count--`. Was that intended?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Not intended. But still the word 'count' doesnt show on console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user clicks the remove option, it runs a function but doesnt decrease the count value

```
    var count = 1;                                                                      
$('.multiple-fields .btn-add').click(function(e) {                                  
    if (count <=4 ){                                                                

        e.preventDefault();

        var multiple_fields = $(this).parents('.multiple-fields');
        var current_entry = $(this).parents('.entry:first');
        var new_entry = $(current_entry.clone()).appendTo(multiple_fields);

        new_entry.find('input').val('');
        new_entry.find('select').val('');
        new_entry.find('.btn-add').removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove').html('<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>');
        new_entry.find('.btn-remove').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parents('.entry').remove();
            count--;
            return false;
        });
        new_entry.find('.select-course, .select-dormitory').change(function() {
            $.campusHandler.update($(this));
        });
        count++;
        console.log(count);
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log(count);
        $.messageHandler.showMessageBox('error_line_max');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$('.multiple-fields .btn-remove').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.entry').remove();
    count--;
    console.log('count');

    return false;
});
```

Focus on this part

Change:

```
        new_entry.find('.btn-remove').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parents('.entry').remove();
            return false;
        });
```

To:

```
new_entry.find('.btn-remove').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.entry').remove();
    count--;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I didnt noticed I repeated the same thing again.